# How to retrieve field values and its translations from Microsoft dynamics CRM using REST API

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online

I need to retrieve the entities from my CRM site and all the fields associated with that entity. Need to get the translated values as well.

Please provide some queries that will be helpful in this case

I tried with below queries, but this could not fetch all the values.

- ..../api/data/v9.1/EntityDefinitions(LogicalName='account')/Attributes/Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.PicklistAttributeMetadata?$select=LogicalName&$expand=OptionSet,GlobalOptionSet
- ..../api/data/v9.1/EntityDefinitions(LogicalName='account')/Attributes
- ..../api/data/v9.1/GlobalOptionSetDefinitions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve CRM entities by calling:

**[Organization URI]/api/data/v9.1/**

In order to get an entity's attributes you can call:

**[Organization URI]/api/data/v9.1/EntityDefinitions(LogicalName='[Entity name (ex: account)]')/Attributes**

For attribute translation, navigate to 'DisplayName' you will find 'LocalizedLabels'.

For more information you can check this url:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/webapi/query-metadata-web-api

Comment: I am able to get some of the field names related to a particular entity using this way, but many translations are missing. Its missing the field values and some other translation data

Comment: I have the object id of each fields/values for which i need to check the translation, is there any way i can use it in any query?